# Как отправить сообщение, которое видит только 1 пользователь? Бот Дискорда

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

Код:

```py
from discord.ext import commands
PREFIX = '/'
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = PREFIX)
im = 'important information'

@client.command()
async def info(ctx):
    await ctx.send(im) #это сообщение должен увидеть только отправитель

token = open('token.txt', 'r').readline()
client.run(token)
```

Я слышал, что для этого используют `respond`, не вышло.
Код, который я пробовал.

```py
async def info(ctx):
    await ctx.respond(im)
```

Answer (score 2):

Метода `respond` нет в discord.py, но есть, например, в библиотеке [discord-components](https://pypi.org/project/discord-components/)
Я думаю это [то](https://discord-components.readthedocs.io/en/0.5.2.4/pages/context.html?highlight=respond#discord_components.context.Context.respond), что вам нужно

```
from discord_components import DiscordComponents, Button
DiscordComponents(bot)
await ctx.send(
        "Hello, World!",
        components = [
            Button(label = "WOW button!", custom_id = "button1")
        ]
    )

interaction = await bot.wait_for("button_click", check = lambda i: i.custom_id == "button1")
await interaction.respond(content="Button clicked!")
```

Comment: Да, это оно, но я не понимаю, как именно это использовать? Как это подставить в код?Вот код:   ` from discord.ext import commands
from discord_components import DiscordComponents
PREFIX = '/'
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = PREFIX)
im = 'important information'

@client.command()
async def info(ctx):
    async respond(im) #это сообщение должен увидеть только отправитель

token = open('token.txt', 'r').readline()
client.run(token)`

Comment: Там есть [документация](https://devkiki7000.gitbook.io/discord-components/) Исправил ответ, дописав код.